# Vir ao trabalho X vir trabalhar

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Essas frases têm o mesmo sentido?

> Ele não veio ao trabalho hoje.
>
> Ele não veio trabalhar hoje.

Ou seja, normalmente, posso substituir **vir ao trabalho** sempre por **vir trabalhar**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sempre. Dependendo do contexto podem ter o mesmo significado, mas não são sinônimos:

- em "vir ao trabalho", trabalho pode denotar um lugar, o de trabalho; enquanto
- "vir trabalhar" costuma implicar a intenção de trabalhar.

Por exemplo:

> – Ele veio trabalhar hoje?
>    – Não, ele está doente e veio ao trabalho só para entregar o atestado médico.